# OpenLayers 2.13.1 - edit and export GeoJSON property values

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openlayers, geojson

I have created an application with OpenLayers 4.1.0 that imports GeoJSON vector data, allows selecting of polygons, changes "processed" property value of selected polygon from 0 to 1 and prepares edited data for export.

Code is here:
https://github.com/mleontenko/openlayers-edit-properties/blob/master/map.html

Now, I'm trying to rewrite that application in OL 2.13.1:
https://github.com/mleontenko/openlayers2-edit-properties/blob/master/map.html

This is the part i can't figure out how to rewrite in OL2:

```
//change "processed" property value from 0 to 1
select.getFeatures().item(0).set('processed', 1);

//store geojson to variable for export 
var writer = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var geojsonStr = writer.writeFeatures(vectorSource.getFeatures());enter code here
```

What it needs to do is:

-Change selected polygon's "processed" property from 0 to 1

-store GeoJson to variable as string so i can export it later